# Mail server using docker and SWAG

Tags: linux, docker, email, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to build my own home server, and I'm trying to integrate mailu with SWAG but I'm unable to do that. Everytime I run docker image I come accross **502 error** in my nginx reverse proxy. My **mailu docker-compose.yml** file

```
  front:
    image: mailu/nginx:master
    restart: always
    env_file: mailu.env
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:25:25"       # SMTP
      - "0.0.0.0:465:465"     # SMTP
      - "0.0.0.0:587:587"     # SMTP (out)
      - "0.0.0.0:143:143"     # IMAP plain
      - "0.0.0.0:993:993"     # IMAP secure
```

and **nginx** mailu subdomain config file

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name mailu.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app front;
        set $upstream_port 80;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my mailu.subdomain.conf looks like the the following (and works):

```
`server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name mailu.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    # enable for ldap auth, fill in ldap details in ldap.conf
    #include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;

    # enable for Authelia
    #include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;

    location / {
        # enable the next two lines for http auth
        #auth_basic "Restricted";
        #auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
`
```

I have to mention that I can not reach ports 993 578 465 .. from the outside :-/ but the web interface, internal database connection etc works.
imap 993 redirects to port 143 for authentication
I'm lost too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).